# No Ui Slider - initialize with jquery.data() method

Tags: jquery, nouislider

```
<!-- slider container -->
<div class="sliderContainer">
  <!--  no ui slider slider div -->
  <div class="slider"
  data-start="100"
  data-min="0"
  data-max="3000">
  </div>
  <-- hidden input that should be bond to the sliders value -->     
  <input type="hidden" class="sliderInput" name="stuff" value="0">
</div>

$(function(){
  $('.slider').noUiSlider({
    start: [$(this).data(" start ")],
      range: {
        'min': $(this).data(" min "),
        'max': $(this).data(" max ")
      }
  });
```

I am using the noUiSlider.js plugin for a form I am building.
Since there is more than one slider in the form I wanted more of a dynamic way to create them.

Since calling `$('.slider')` returns an array of html `.slider` elements, I thought I could use the `$(this)` identifier but it doesnt seem to work, also if I try something like : `$(.slider)[0].data("max");` it wont work.

I am thinking of trying to loop through the array,
but I am really starting to think that perhaps I don't understand how the `data()` function works..

Comment: `$('.slider').each(function(){ console.log($(this).data('start')); })`?

Comment: Killed it. Going to look at the each() function. 
This already a big breakthrough thanks!